# Is there a way to proxy a request with Nginx without client knowing the request was proxied?

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have an app making a request to `www.example.com/blocked` that is blocked by a browser plugin which results with an error `GET http://www.example.com/blocked net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`. When in the app I change the request to go instead to my Nginx `www.myproxyserver.ml/proxy`, where I then proxy the request to the original website, the app still comes back with the same error message above. I am trying to find a way not to reveal the end request back to client, rather the proxy server address.

This is the Nginx config:

```
server {
        server_name                     myproxyserver.ml;
        access_log                      off;
        resolver                        8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;

        location /proxy {
                proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding "";
                proxy_pass              https://www.example.com/blocked;
                break;
        }
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
}
```

I have tried setting the headers with `proxy_set_header` in the config for various settings, but didn't manage to properly proxy the request, rather just redirect it.

Thank you.

Comment: This isn't a issue with how the proxy works, but how the browser plugin works. Figure out that, possibly by looking into the source of the plugin.

Comment: It's an ad blocker plugin that blocks requests that contain a certain keyword. For instance, 'ads', 'analytics' etc. Say url on my server that I want to hit is 'example.com/analytics', it will get blocked. This is what I want to route it over another url and figured Nginx proxy had a way to do it. Doesn't it?

Comment: It obviously doesn't solely match URL. Otherwise the reverse proxy would fool it.

Comment: @vidarlo could you please elaborate?

If I change just part of the request url string, so it doesn't contain 'analytics', the plugin doesn't block the request and I get back status 404. 

How would you make the reverse proxy do the trick?

Comment: Have a look at the headers. Probably the site sends a redirect or similar. Without real hostnames and URLs it's difficult for us to debug behaviour.

Comment: i think you need to explain a hell more, what your doing not only your nginx config will not be all, since you are telling your writing(?) an app that blocks requests, i would suggest to think about at least 100% more information needed. Moreover - Please FOCUS your question!

Comment: @djdomi I think the primary problem you have here is English comprehension, not the focus of my question.